# Unnumbered line inside align

Tags: equations, numbering, align

Basically, I have two equations that I wanted to use align to number, but I also wanted to put the word 'and' in between the lines.
Here's what I have so far

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align}
  \mathrm{distance} &= \mathrm{speed} \times \mathrm{time}\\
  &\text{and}\\
  y &= \mathrm{m}x + \mathrm{c}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the equations in the way that I want them but it numbers the line that says 'and'. Hopefully, if this made any sense, someone can help me with this.

Comment: There is `\nonumber`/`\notag` but here, typographically speaking, you should use `\intertext{and}` or `\shortintertext{and}` from the `mathtools` package instead (you can slip a `\centering` in there).

Comment: Ah okay, cool, thanks. Looking at it now, I'm fairly sure I've used this before, I knew it wasn't difficult. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% please change to your document class
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{mydef}
\begin{align}
\text{distance} &= \text{speed} \times \text{time}\\
\intertext{and}
y &= \mathrm{m}x + \mathrm{c}
\end{align}
\end{mydef}


\begin{mydef}
\begin{align}
\mathrm{distance} &= \mathrm{speed} \times \mathrm{time}\\
\shortintertext{and}
y &= \mathrm{m}x + \mathrm{c}
\end{align}
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

### Remarks:

Compare the results in the first and the second theorems carefully.

- Use `\text` when you want its content to be affected by the surrounding font. For example, if `\text` is used inside a theorem environment, the surrounding font is italic so the contents of `\text` will be in italic as well.
- Use `\mathrm` when you don't want its contents to be affected by the surrounding font.
- Use `\intertext` for getting normal spacing but `\shortintertext` for shorter one.

Comment: Oh right, okay, cheers. I'm kinda just getting used to this trying to write my first lab report for uni with it. This is really great, I didn't really understand what \mathrm was I was just using it. Thanks again, really helpful!

Comment: Use `\centering` inside the `intertext` commands for a more readable centred layout, e.g., `\shortintertext{\centering and}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


\begin{align}
  \mathrm{distance} &= \mathrm{speed} \times \mathrm{time}\\
  \noalign{\text{and}}
  y &= \mathrm{m}x + \mathrm{c}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that was so simple. I feel pretty stupid now. I knew there would be some simple fix! Thank you!